# Sqoop - Failed to empty staging table before export

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sqoop

I have faced an interesting situation while trying to export data from HDFS to MySQL database. I'm getting Error during export: Failed to empty staging table before export run.

First I created two tables in MySQL and executed Sqoop export statement for the first time (when both tables were empty).

As a result records from the staging table migrated to the export table successfully:

```
INFO manager.SqlManager: Migrated 81424802 records from `staging_weather_data` to `export_weather_data`
```

However when I executed a SELECT query on the `export_weather_data` table (`SELECT count(*) FROM export_weather_data;`
) - it returned 0 records. **How could the table remain empty if the records migrated successfully?**

As for the `staging_weather_data` table - it contains the exported records.

So I decided to retry Sqoop export with the same statement:

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/weather_data \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager \
--table export_weather_data \
--staging-table staging_weather_data \
--clear-staging-table \
--export-dir /user/maria_dev/input-sqoop \
--options-file ~/.access_credentials \
--num-mappers 4 \
--batch \
--input-fields-terminated-by ','
```

After that I keep getting the following Error:

```
INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of export_weather_data
18/03/22 13:28:57 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Unable to execute delete query: DELETE FROM `staging_weather_data`
java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Failed to empty staging table before export run
```

The only thing I could suspect is the absence of `--clear-staging-table` attribute but I had it in the statement from the very beginning. So for now I have no ideas how to solve it and need any suggestions.

Comment: Can you check the record count on the staging table? Looks like the error is while transferring records from staging to the target table.

Comment: @vmorusu you are right. The `staging_weather_data` table did not contain all records. So I deleted it and created a new empty staging table. After that I retried sqoop export and it executed correctly - all the data appeared in the `export_weather_data` table as well.